# Как удалить зависимые строки в таблицы с внешним ключом?

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы. "Карты" и "Покупки"

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS card(
           id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,

           user_id INTEGER,
           number TEXT,
           pin TEXT,
           balance INTEGER DEFAULT 0
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,

            card_id INTEGER,
            adress TEXT,
            sum INTEGER,

            FOREIGN KEY (card_id) REFERENCES card (id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

При попытке удаления карты `DELETE FROM card WHERE number=1 AND user_id=1`- история покупок этой карты остаются. Как сделать так чтобы при удалении карты - удалялась и история покупок?

Comment: У вас number text, а вы удаляет число. Может он его интерпретирует не как текст. Попробуйте 1 в кавычки поставить.

Comment: @Игорь поправил, но проблему это не решило. Зависимые таблицы не удаляются..